# Is it possible to merge two tables in Power Query Editor (Power BI) with Python fuzzy matching?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery, fuzzy-comparison

**Merge two tables in power query editor (Power BI) based on string similarity with Python**

Consider the tables bellow:

**Table1**

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYEoi.jpg)

| Name | ... |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Fruit A11 | ... |
| Banana Fruit B12 | ... |
| ... | ... |

**Table2**

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8gVK.jpg)

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Apple A11R/T | 40 |
| B4n4n4 Fruit B12_T | 50 |
| Berry A11 | 60 |
| ... | ... |

I want to get the **Value** from **Table2** into **Table1**. But for some reason when I use the built-in power query editor merge with fuzzy matching. It will match *Apple Fruit A11* with *Berry A11* instead of *Apple A11 R/T*. I've read the documentation, and it says that the built-in function works best with single words. I tried to remove spaces both from **Table1[Name]** and **Table2[Name]** but it didn't improve results.

I looked around trying to find a solution, but wasn't able to figure out yet. Is there a way to do this using python? Or is there a simpler solution?

The results that I am expecting:

**Table1**

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO259.jpg)

| Name | ... | Table2.Name | Table2.Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Fruit A11 | ... | Apple A11R/T | 40 |
| Banana Fruit B12 | ... | B4n4n4 Fruit B12_T | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

--- For some reason the tables are not showing up like the preview, that's why there are also images for each table. **Disclaimer: The data present in the tables above is just an example of the pattern of the data that I am working with. And fuzzy matching will probably give the right results for the example data.**

Comment: Is there a specific python method you want to use for this?

Comment: @horseyride Not really, I'm just having trouble finding any source of information about how to apply any matching method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuzzy matching in Power Query works fine for me.

[image]

Set your options to the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the table is just an example since I can't publish the data that I am working with. It just follows the same patterns I have in my data.
The weirdest part is that, for example, if I recreate a shorter version of my table only with the items that are malfunctioning, fuzzy matching manages to do it right.